# Django - one field to many columns in db table

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to create a custom field with choices that store data in n (number of choices) db columns. It's should looks like dummy vector.

Example:

1. [Choose type of product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRswN.jpg)
2. This product in db table

| id | kind_hygine | kind_road_equipment | kind_relax | kind_food |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

It is a legacy db, so I can not change db tables layout.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

model.py

```
YOUR_CHOICES = [
       ("Road equipment","Road equipment"),
       ("Relax","Relax"),...
       #it goes like this create list inside it create tuples as many as you want
       #inside every tuple create 2 string elements the first is one will be 
       #stored inside your DB the seconde is the one will be shown to the user
]

class YourModel(models.Model):
    .... #other model fields
    your_choices_field= models.CharField(choices=YOUR_CHOICES)
```

now in your form

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
   your_choices_field=forms.ChoiceField(choices=YOUR_CHOICES)
```

Comment: I have already tried this. But it does not write to the database the way I need it (it looks like [this](https://postimg.cc/jwpHPm5M))

Comment: @TheodorLisin if you didn't try this it should work